# Java decompression of files from solr server

Tags: java, solr, gzip, compression

I am getting error when i am trying to decompressing the files coming from server,but i am getting error of invalid bit length in while loop.Is there any problem with code or encoding.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        FileInputStream fileInput = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = null; 
        System.out.println(source_compressed_filepath);
        System.out.println(destinaton_decompressed_filepath);
        try {           
            fileInput = new FileInputStream(source_compressed_filepath);
            gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(fileInput);
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinaton_decompressed_filepath);
            int len;
            while ((len = gzipInputStream.read(buffer)) >=0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }                   
            System.out.println("The file" + source_compressed_filepath + " was DeCompressed successfully!"
                    + destinaton_decompressed_filepath);
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(" error in file decompression " + source_compressed_filepath);
        } finally {
            // close resources
            try {
                fileOutputStream.close();
                gzipInputStream.close();            

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
```

Comment: can you open file files using a normal zip utility?

Comment: No,when i used zipEntry for compressing 0Kb file is generated

Comment: Then what algo i have to use for decompressing.